# how to display button on other button click?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular10

I am trying to display this: when a button is clicked then another button will be displayed and the clicked one will hide (and the not clicked one will show). Something like when the (-) is clicked then the (+) show (the minus disappear) and vice versa, they won't show both at the same time. How can achieve this?

[image]

This is the code that I tried

```
<td>
    <a class="action-btn" ng-init="InActive=true" ng-model="Inactive" ng-click="InActive=false" >
        <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
    </a>
</td>
<td>
    <a class="action-btn" ng-show="Inactive" ng-click="Active=!Active">
        <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

I use Angular version 10

Comment: Can you attach a sample code? It will be hard to guess blindly.

Comment: Which version of angular did you use? Can you post what you tried so far, a [example], so we can see where to support you 